# What PHP version is supported by which TYPO3 release?

Tags: php, compatibility, typo3

I'm planning on upgrade my PHP to version 5.3. Most of my sites are running on the TYPO3 framework. Some of this have an install before TYPO3 version 4.5. Are there any known issues of older TYPO3 versions and PHP 5.3?

I can't find anything about system requirements for this older TYPO3 versions.

Comment: For newer versions, see "PHP compatibility chart" on official page: https://typo3.org/cms/roadmap/

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**TYPO3 Versions at a Glance** https://get.typo3.org

**TYPO3 Installation Guide (official documentation)** https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-installation/main/en-us/

**TYPO3 Versions on Wikipedia:** http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TYPO3

---

The following tables give you more details about TYPO3 version requirements.

**Status 28.04.2022**

- **For up-to-date information, check on** https://get.typo3.org!
- values in table based on information on get.typo3.org
- only MySQL is listed here, other SQL DBMS are supported as well

| version | Status | PHP | MySQL | LTS until | ELTS until |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| v12 | in progress ... |  |  |  |  |
| v11 | LTS | 7.4, 8.0, 8.1 | 5.7+ | 2024-10-31 | 2027-10-31 |
| v10 | LTS | 7.2, 7.3, 7.4 | 5.5+ | 2023-04-30 | 2026-04-30 |
| v9 | ELTS | 7.2, 7.3, 7.4 | >= 5.0 <= 5.7 | 2021-09-30 | 2024-09-30 |
| v8 | ELTS | >= 7.0.8 <= 7.4.99 | >= 5.0 <= 5.7 | 2020-03-31 | 2023-03-31 |
| v7 | ELTS | >= 5.5.0 <= 7.3.99 | >= 5.5 <= 5.7 | 2018-11-27 | 2022-11-30 |

---

**Status 06.02.2015**

[image]

---

**Status 07.11.2014**

Typo3 is now called TYPO3 CMS

[image]

---

**Status 24.07.2014**

[image]

---

**Status 15.08.2012**

[image]

---

**Status 28.12.2010**

[image]

---

Currently I am running TYPO3 4.6 with PHP 5.4.x and I had no issues so far.

Comment: Thanks! I simply missed that link on on the Typo3 website.

Comment: You can find old versions of the download page (i.e. the info in the above tables) using the Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/*/typo3.org/download